# Разорвать связи листа с помощью VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Каким VBA скриптом можно разорвать все ссылки активного листа на соседние листы той же книги и превратить их в значения? Тоисть если в формуле ячейки задействована ссылка на другой лист превращать эту формулу в значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно проверять наличие имени листа в формуле. Вариант не очень хороший.

**Пример.** В книге есть лист *кекс*

```
=ЕСЛИ(A1=1;"очень вкусный кекс";"")
```

В формуле нет сылки на другой лист *кекс*, но она по ошибке будет преобразована в значение.

Проверять имя листа с восклицательным знаком (*кекс!*)? Да. Но этого мало: если имя листа имеет пробелы, в формуле оно окружено апострофами (*'вкусные кексы'!*) и само имя отделено от восклицательного знака.

**Вывод:** или дополнительно обрабатывать тест формулы, или для каждого листа проверять по два значения. Второе проще и быстрее.

```
Sub FormulasInValues()
Dim aShtName()
Dim sht As Worksheet, c
Dim j As Long
' ==========================================================='
Dim aLog(), k As Long
    ReDim aLog(1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
' ==========================================================='
    ReDim aShtName(1 To (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) * 2)

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.name <> ActiveSheet.name Then
            j = j + 1: aShtName(j) = sht.name & "!"
            j = j + 1: aShtName(j) = sht.name & "'!"
        End If
    Next sht

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        For j = 1 To UBound(aShtName)
            If c.HasFormula Then
                If InStr(c.Formula, aShtName(j)) > 0 Then
' =================================================='
                    k = k + 1: aLog(k, 1) = c.Address
' =================================================='
                    c.Value = c.Value: Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next c
' ======================================================'
    If k > 0 Then Cells(10, 10).Resize(k, 1).Value = aLog
    MsgBox "Заменено формул: " & k, 64, ""
' ======================================================'
End Sub
```

Для того, чтобы для каждой ячейки заново не определять имена и не сравнивать с именем активного листа, формируем массив.

*If c.HasFormula Then* - проверяем только ячейки с формулами.

Три фрагмента кода, обведенные "рамками" - формирование списка адресов ячеек, в которых удалены формулы. Эти пять строк могут быть безболезненно исключены из макроса.

*Cells(10, 10)* - указать ссылку за пределами используемого диапазона листа или вывести список на отдельный лист.

**Но и тут возможен сюрприэ**

```
 ="по адресу ""кексы!C3"" лежит конфета"
```

Маловероятно, но возможно. Для полной безопасности перед удалением формулы ставим еще одну проверку:

```
If IsError(Evaluate(Replace(c.Formula, aShtName(j), "!!!"))) Then
     ' меняем формулу на значение
End If
```

Т.е. если в формуле обнаружен фрагмент с именем листа, заменяем его на что-то неестественное для имени, пробуем вычислить формулу. И если ошибки нет, значит, ложная тревога - фрагмент, похожий на ссылку, присутствует только в текстовой строке.
Важно именно менять, а не удалять имя (замена на ""): при удалении останется ссылка на ячейки активного листа и  *IsError=False* - формула со ссылкой на другой лист не удалится.

**И это еще не все**

После дополнения *IsError* возможна еще одна ошибка в определении нужной формулы: в формуле в текстовой строке присутствует фрагмент с именем другого листа и сама формула по каким-либо причинам выдает ошибку.

Вернемся к первому примеру с листом *кекс*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A1=1;"очень вкусный кекс!";"")
```

при этом *A1=НД()*

Наша созданная конструкция честно проверит все три условия: увидит формулу в ячейке; найдет в ней имя листа с восклицательным знаком; проверит, что ошибка есть - и преобразует формулу в результат ее работы!

Для такого практически невероятного случая (но мало ли...): исключать из проверки ячейки с формулами,  показывающими ошибки. Потом в ручном режиме ненужное менять на значения. При обработке можно создать список исключенных адресов.

Но это костыль. А правильно: не допускать в работе формул появления ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each OneCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ThisSheetName").UsedRange
    If Instr(OneCell.Formula, "AnotherSheetName") > 0 Then
        OneCell.Value = OneCell.Value
    End If
Next
```

Более строго - писать свой парсинг формулы, выделять из формулы имя листа и ячейки (которое там может быть не одно), после чего проверять, что у полученной ячейки (хотя бы одной) текущая ячейка входит в список Dependents, и если да - выполнять переприсвоение.